# throwing UnauthorizedAccessException when accessing an image file

Tags: c#, file, unauthorized, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I have a problem with accessing and copying an image file. Here my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        string fileName = "";

        fileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        string newPath = @"C:\Users\grafik5\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug";
        string newFileName = @"image";

        string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

        openFileDialog1.Dispose();

        newPath = Path.Combine(newPath, newFileName + ext);         

        if (fileName != "")
        {
            try
            {
                FileSecurity oFileSecurity = new FileSecurity();
                oFileSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
                File.SetAccessControl(fileName, oFileSecurity);

            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {              
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }

            File.Copy(fileName, newPath, true);

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\grafik5\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe";
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

            flag1 = true;
        }
    }
```

I don't know what I need to do. My program always throws the error message.
Another process will read the copied image. It will do image processing. 
There is no problem with the process of working. I checked it.

> Error is at File.SetAccessControl(fileName, oFileSecurity);

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Yes you left out the most important bit of information, both `File.SetAccessControl` and `File.Copy` can throw `UnauthorizedAccessException` and in both cases you may not have permissions to do that

Answer (score 1):

Any young *Codeling Jedi* should have looked at the documentation, which i assume you have. However -

[File.SetAccessControl Method (String, FileSecurity)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setaccesscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Applies access control list (ACL) entries described by a FileSecurity
>   object to the specified file.

**Exceptions**

> UnauthorizedAccessException
>
> - The path parameter specified a file that is read-only.
> - This operation is not supported on the current platform.
> - The path parameter specified a directory.
> - The caller does not have the required permission.

This is probably a permissions thing. The easiest fix, is make sure your application has the appropriate permissions to do this.

Either

- Elevate your app by running it as *Administrator*,
- Give your user the appropriate permissions to set the *ACL*

However it should be wise and prudent, to check if the other conditions apply